# Doubt on proof of characterization of polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

I was trying to understand [this](https://mathoverflow.net/a/34067/156428) proof of the following result:

> If $f \in \mathcal{C}^\infty (\mathbb{R})$ satisfies that for every $x
> > \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists a $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
> $f^{(n)}(x)=0$, then $f$ is a polynomial.

However I don't really understand how Baire's category theorem is applied. Could anyone explain how is it applied?

Now, I was thinking that if we could state that $\operatorname{int}X \not= \emptyset$ then by Baire's category theorem, $X \cap S_n \not= \emptyset$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and then we have a contradiction because if we take $x \in \operatorname{int}(X \cap S_n)$ then there exists an interval $(a,b)$ that contains $x$ such that
$$(a,b) \subset X \cap S_n$$
so $(f^{(n)})|_{(a,b)}\equiv0$ and then $f|_{(a,b)}$ is a polynomial getting a contradiction with $x \in X$.

So, does any one have any idea if it is possible to prove that $X$ has non empty interior to conclude the proof in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how the theorem is applied:

We make sure that $X$ is a non-empty complete metric space, and $\{X\cap S_n\}$ is its countable closed cover. Here, $closed$ is to be understood with respect to $X$. From Baire's theorem, we deduce that some $X\cap S_n$ contains a non-empty open set. Here, $open$ is to be understood with respect to $X$. Open sets in $X$ are of the form $U\cap X$, where $U$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$. So we deduce that some open interval $(a, b)$ has a non-empty intersection with $X$, and $$(a, b)\cap X\subset X\cap S_n.$$

Comment: Oh, it was applied to $X$ as a complete metric space not to $\mathbb{R}$, I see it know, thanks.

Comment: If you know the proof, could you also explain the end of it? I mean, why can you consider a maximal interval in $(a,b) \setminus X$? And, I get that $(a,b) \cap X$ and $(c,e)$ are contained in $S_n$ but how do we know that all of $(a,b)$ is in $S_n$ as it is stated at the end?

Comment: @Eparoh Sure. $(c, e)$ is one of the connected components, which constitute $(a, b)\setminus X$. Since each of them is contained in $S_n$, so does $(a, b)\setminus X$. Together with $(a, b)\cap X\subset S_n$ this gives $(a, b)\subset S_n$

Comment: Thanks a lot! But, if $(c,e)$ is a connected componet of $(a,b) \setminus X$ then why is it that $c$ or $e$ belongs to  $(a,b) \cap X$? Couldn't it be that $c,e$ are not in $(a,b)$ nor in $X$?

Comment: @Eparoh In that case, $(a, b)\subset (c, e)\subset (a, b)\setminus X$, which contradicts the assumption that $(a, b)$ intersects $X$

Comment: Okay, now everything is clear. Thank you so much for helping me! :)